# Jasmine Karma . Test failing after a specific number of tests(page reload error)

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, page-refresh

I am testing an angular application using karma jasmine, I have about 10 spec files , with a total of 10 describes and 48 test cases. The problem is that ,I am  getting an error whenever the test case exceeds 47, the error says , some of the tests did a full page reload. i tried by commenting out random test cases and limited to 47 , then it works fine. even a blank 48th test case is giving the error ,

```
"jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
"jshint-stylish": "^1.0.0",
"karma": "^0.13.21",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
"karma-coverage": "^0.5.3",
"karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.7",
"karma-jasmine": "^0.3.7",
"karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.2.1",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
```

this is my version of karma and related dependencies .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It relates to one or more of your your tests doing reloads. Unfortunately Karma doesn't tell you which.

Here's a solution from this [issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1101).

1) Run your app with the following code included before anything else and DevTools (Chrome, in this case) open.

```
console.profile('cause of reload');

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
    console.profileEnd('cause of reload');
    debugger;
});
```

If the reload you're looking for happens, you should be taken to the "Sources" view of Chrome Devtools with the app paused at the debugger line.

2) Navigate to "Profiles" tab and choose the "Charts" view.

3) Command+F and search for "location".

4) Use the up and down arrows in the search box to jump to the last occuring matches for that phrase.

5) Hit enter in the search field to jump to the match.

6) Look back through the call stack for code you recognise.

Credit to [JamieMason](https://github.com/JamieMason)

Comment: I cannot see a charts view option in profile tab , select profiling type is the option i am seeing , kindly help

Comment: Hmm.. maybe that's for an older version. You should see a profile called "cause of reload" just open that and you can do a search in the default view.

Comment: i tried that , but i have no location reload functions in any of my scripts , the error still exists , but i found another solution from another thread, it says increasing 
maximumSpecCallbackDepth from 20 to a higher value. which is located in jasmine-core/lib/jasmine.js

Comment: That may solve the error for testing, but I'd run some careful profiling on the page itself to see if there is something firing too many times...

Answer (score 0):

I am just using an anchor tag with href but because that reloads it would fail for me as well with **"Some of your tests did a full page reload!"**. I wanted to test a function being called during the click so this was my solution in the test:

```
    const link = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('a'));
    link.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
```

The issue was with this:

```
    link.click();
```

This way you can trigger a click without having it navigate and refresh the page.